# Unable to install any modules with Pip and this error

Tags: python, installation, syntax-error, libraries, python-module

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1fWQk.png)

I have installed python on my windows laptop appropriately but am unable to use or execute many things due to this kind of error. How do I come out of the shell and execute

I want to install modules and libraries on python and want to get rid of this error.

Comment: Don't take screenshots of your problem. It's against the SO usage rules and this question should be closed for that. Place the code and output here so that it can be easily searched by others who have the same question as you.

Comment: You're trying to execute `pip install numpy` as python code.  It is not python code.

Answer (score 0):

`pip` is not a command for the interpreter, it is a module.
To invoke pip you should enter `python3 -m pip install numpy` on your command line.

Comment: [Here's a tutorial](https://youtu.be/7snh_1Hf_TI?si=TUbpr86F2YRHCcta)

Answer (score 0):

You have gone inside the python interpreter by commanding `python3`. You should install from the command line. Just open the command line and type. Only if you want to do interactive task in python then you should go to python interpreter,

Your python version is python-3. So you should install modules with pip as following:

```
pip3 install numpy
```

In some OS(as I saw in some linux distros), some of the modules don't work with the above. In that case, you can use the following:

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade numpy
```